# Knex migrations with Electron and sqlite?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, electron, offline, knex.js

I am using sqlite as my database for an offline app which is made in electron.
For creating the database, I was using knex migrations.
Problem is, it will run fine in development, i would migrate the database and start the electron process.

But while packaging the app for production build, I need the migrations to run on the client machine on the first start up. So that the database would be created and when there is an application update, a new migration would keep the database updated.

What is the appropriate approach for this. How do i run the migrations on app start up, or how do i keep the migrations in the bundle.
Won't all the code be kept in app.asar? Will the migration code be run from there?

Also, where should the database be created in the client machine?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey did you find anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using electron builder then you can add this to the electron-builder.json

`"extraFiles": "migrations/*",`
 where *migrations* is the folder where you keep the migrations.

To migrate it automatically on running 
you can add the following code 

`const client = knex(config[env]);
client.migrate.latest(config);`

Comment: this should be elaborated on to be more helpful. Like where the code would be run from.

Comment: I am using express js server so all my database queries go here, I just created a specific route for executing the migrations, and I call it once when the app starts, it works fine.

Comment: What does your knexfile look like?